# Is there any plan from Geckodriver to remove "overlappingcheckdisabled" capability?

Tags: selenium, geckodriver, selenium3

I have been using Firefox to run my tests for a while and in my tests it is required to have "overlappingcheckdisabled" capability set to true, otherwise it would break my tests and it would be a pain:

```
capabilities.setCapability("overlappingCheckDisabled", true);
```

I have checked ChromeDriver does not recognize that capability and when I try to use ChromeDriver instead of Geckodriver it throws the following error: 
*"Element is not clickable at point (x, y). Other element would receive the click"*

Do you know if there is any plan from Geckodriver to remove that capability or make it useless? (I hope not). It would also be useful to know where I can get that info.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please show a little more code? I'm trying to set that capability for one of my tests and I get an exception about Firefox options.

Comment: Maybe this can help you @DavidClarke . In my case I am using WebDriver. Capabilities lines are the same. Differences are CommandExecutor and WebDriver:    
`DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();      capabilities.setCapability("overlappingCheckDisabled", true);    

CommandExecutor executor = new SeleneseCommandExecutor(new URL("http://localhost:4444/"), new URL("http://www.google.com/"), capabilities);    
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(executor, **capabilities**);`

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo, I'll check that out. At the moment I'm executing some script to click the link on a page.